# How can I restart failed sharepoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

How can I restart failed sharepoint 2010 workflow automatically which shows "Error Occurred"?

I know we can trigger the workflow manually. But I want to restart workflow automatically when workflow got failed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Its not recommended to leave a workflow in "Error Occurred" state. Check for all the errors within your workflow only.

Comment: If I run the workflow manually I didn't get any Error Message. Workflow ran successfully, every time I can't go and start the workflow manually.so I need an automatic solution for restart the failed workflow.

Answer (score 0):

**`Restart workflow on fail Automatically`** is **not** available in SharePoint Designer workflow.

**Workarounds**

- Enable Manual workflow start.
- Instead of SharePoint Designer Workflow, try to use [Microsoft flow](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/) to be able to [resubmit a flow that has failed automatically](https://ms.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-runs/).
- Use a 3rd party tool

Comment: Microsoft flow for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: In tags, he mentioned SharePoint online! Also, he didn't say he use SharePoint 2010, he uses the SharePoint Workflow 2010 platform in SharePoint online!!! Hope it clear!

Comment: Ok. Can we terminate the running workflow using MS Flow? Because to re-run the workflow on that item, we need to terminate using - "End this workflow"right?

Comment: 1. You can't 2. Yes!

Comment: By the way, I mentioned MS flow as an alternative for Designer workflow, not to use it to rerun Designer workflow that has failed!

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to know if there is any action in flow.

Comment: You're welcome bro, have a nice night!